# How do show the date that a post was made on?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating a simple jobs board and would like to show the date that the post was created in the format - 'Posted on: 11th February 2015'

I would like to show it in two places, in my index (index.html.erb) with the post and in the individual post pages (show.html.erb)

My current code is as follows:

index.html.erb -

```
    <p><%= link_to "Add a Position", new_job_path %></p>

    <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
        <div class="job">
            <%= link_to job.position, job %>
            <br><br>
            <ul class="entry_list">
                <li>Company: <%= job.company %></li>
                <li>Salary: <%= job.salary %></li>
                <li>Contract Type: <%= job.contract %></li>
                <li>City: <%= job.city %></li>
                <li>Expiry date: <%= job.expirydate %></li>
                <li>Job Type: <%= job.jobtype %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <p><%= paginate @jobs %></p>
```

show.html.erb -

```
    <%= @job.position %>
    <ul>
      <li>Company: <%= @job.company %></li>
      <li>Salary: <%= @job.salary %></li>
      <li>Contract Type: <%= @job.contract %></li>
      <li>City: <%= @job.city %></li>
      <li>Expiry date: <%= @job.expirydate %></li>
      <li>Job Type: <%= @job.jobtype %></li>
      <li><%= @job.description %></li>
      <li>How to apply: <%= @job.apply %></li>
    </ul>
```

job.rb -

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :position, presence: true
  validates :company, presence: true
  validates :salary, presence: true
  validates :companywebsite, presence: true
  validates :companytwitter, presence: true
  validates :contract, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :expirydate, presence: true
  validates :jobtype, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :apply, presence: true
  validates :contactname, presence: true
  validates :contactemail, presence: true
  validates :contactphone, presence: true
end
```

jobs_controller.rb -

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  def index
     @jobs = Job.page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end

  def new
     @job = Job.new
  end

  def show
     @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
     @job = Job.new(params.require(:job).permit(:position, :company, :salary, :companywebsite, :companytwitter, :contract, :city, :expirydate, :jobtype, :description, :apply, :contactname, :contactemail, :contactphone, ))
    if @job.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use strftime for that.

```
<%= job.created_at.strftime("#{job.created_at.day.ordinalize} %B %Y") %>
```

"Posted on" you'll need to put in statically.

More about [ordinalize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/ordinalize)

Comment: Thats awesome and works for the index page (index.html.erb) however its returning a 'NameError in Jobs#show' error when I use the same code in show.html.erb, how can I fix this?

Comment: Add an `@` to the front

Answer (score 1):

(This is an addition to [japed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28453918/477037), but too long for a comment)

Since you need this in several places, you can add your own time format:

```
# config/initializers/time_formats.rb
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:short_ordinal] = ->(time) { time.strftime("#{time.day.ordinalize} %B %Y") }
```

and call [`to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) or its alias `to_s`:

```
job.created_at.to_s(:short_ordinal)
#=> "11th February 2015"
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just define a method to do the strftime conversion in a model (or decorator/presenter if using them).